# What does posenet return?

Tags: java, android, tensorflow, image-processing, tensorflow-lite

I'm working on a project which read an image as an input and show and output image. The output image contains some lines to indicate the human body skeleton. I'm using pose estimation model from tensorflow-lite:

https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/models/pose_estimation/overview

I have read the docs, and it shows that the output contains a 4-dimensions array. I have tried to use netron to visualize my model file and it looks like this:
[image: model visualisation]

I succeeded to get the result heatmap from the input but I got a problem that all the float are negative. It makes me confused and I'm not sure if I did anything wrong or how to understand these outputs.

Here's the code for the output

```java
            tfLite = new Interpreter(loadModelFile());
            Bitmap inputPhoto = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.human2);
            inputPhoto = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(inputPhoto, INPUT_SIZE_X, INPUT_SIZE_Y, false);
            inputPhoto = inputPhoto.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);

            int pixels[] = new int[INPUT_SIZE_X * INPUT_SIZE_Y];

            inputPhoto.getPixels(pixels, 0, INPUT_SIZE_X, 0, 0, INPUT_SIZE_X, INPUT_SIZE_Y);

            int pixelsIndex = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < INPUT_SIZE_X; i ++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < INPUT_SIZE_Y; j++) {
                    int p = pixels[pixelsIndex];
                    inputData[0][i][j][0] = (p >> 16) & 0xff;
                    inputData[0][i][j][1] = (p >> 8) & 0xff;
                    inputData[0][i][j][2] = (p) & 0xff;
                    pixelsIndex ++;
                }
            }

            float outputData[][][][] = new float[1][23][17][17];

            tfLite.run(inputData, outputData);
```

The output is an array [1][23][17][17] which is all negative. So is there anyone who known about this can help me :(

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 2):

This post came Active today so I post a late answer, sorry about that.
You should check the [Posenet.kt file](https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/blob/master/lite/examples/posenet/android/posenet/src/main/java/org/tensorflow/lite/examples/posenet/lib/Posenet.kt). There you can see a very detailed documented code. You can see how this:

> Initializes an outputMap of 1 * x * y * z FloatArrays for the model processing to populate.
> */

```
private fun initOutputMap(interpreter: Interpreter): HashMap<Int, Any> {
    val outputMap = HashMap<Int, Any>()

    // 1 * 9 * 9 * 17 contains heatmaps
    val heatmapsShape = interpreter.getOutputTensor(0).shape()
    outputMap[0] = Array(heatmapsShape[0]) {
      Array(heatmapsShape[1]) {
        Array(heatmapsShape[2]) { FloatArray(heatmapsShape[3]) }
      }
    }

    // 1 * 9 * 9 * 34 contains offsets
    val offsetsShape = interpreter.getOutputTensor(1).shape()
    outputMap[1] = Array(offsetsShape[0]) {
      Array(offsetsShape[1]) { Array(offsetsShape[2]) { FloatArray(offsetsShape[3]) } }
    }

    // 1 * 9 * 9 * 32 contains forward displacements
    val displacementsFwdShape = interpreter.getOutputTensor(2).shape()
    outputMap[2] = Array(offsetsShape[0]) {
      Array(displacementsFwdShape[1]) {
        Array(displacementsFwdShape[2]) { FloatArray(displacementsFwdShape[3]) }
      }
    }

    // 1 * 9 * 9 * 32 contains backward displacements
    val displacementsBwdShape = interpreter.getOutputTensor(3).shape()
    outputMap[3] = Array(displacementsBwdShape[0]) {
      Array(displacementsBwdShape[1]) {
        Array(displacementsBwdShape[2]) { FloatArray(displacementsBwdShape[3]) }
      }
    }

    return outputMap
    }
```

and of course how the output is transformed to points on screen:

```
/**
 * Estimates the pose for a single person.
 * args:
 *      bitmap: image bitmap of frame that should be processed
 * returns:
 *      person: a Person object containing data about keypoint locations and confidence scores
 */
fun estimateSinglePose(bitmap: Bitmap): Person {
    val estimationStartTimeNanos = SystemClock.elapsedRealtimeNanos()
    val inputArray = arrayOf(initInputArray(bitmap))
    Log.i(
        "posenet",
        String.format(
            "Scaling to [-1,1] took %.2f ms",
            1.0f * (SystemClock.elapsedRealtimeNanos() - estimationStartTimeNanos) / 1_000_000
        )
    )

    val outputMap = initOutputMap(getInterpreter())

    val inferenceStartTimeNanos = SystemClock.elapsedRealtimeNanos()
    getInterpreter().runForMultipleInputsOutputs(inputArray, outputMap)
    lastInferenceTimeNanos = SystemClock.elapsedRealtimeNanos() - inferenceStartTimeNanos
    Log.i(
        "posenet",
        String.format("Interpreter took %.2f ms", 1.0f * lastInferenceTimeNanos / 1_000_000)
    )

    val heatmaps = outputMap[0] as Array<Array<Array<FloatArray>>>
    val offsets = outputMap[1] as Array<Array<Array<FloatArray>>>

    val height = heatmaps[0].size
    val width = heatmaps[0][0].size
    val numKeypoints = heatmaps[0][0][0].size

    // Finds the (row, col) locations of where the keypoints are most likely to be.
    val keypointPositions = Array(numKeypoints) { Pair(0, 0) }
    for (keypoint in 0 until numKeypoints) {
        var maxVal = heatmaps[0][0][0][keypoint]
        var maxRow = 0
        var maxCol = 0
        for (row in 0 until height) {
            for (col in 0 until width) {
                if (heatmaps[0][row][col][keypoint] > maxVal) {
                    maxVal = heatmaps[0][row][col][keypoint]
                    maxRow = row
                    maxCol = col
                }
            }
        }
        keypointPositions[keypoint] = Pair(maxRow, maxCol)
    }

    // Calculating the x and y coordinates of the keypoints with offset adjustment.
    val xCoords = IntArray(numKeypoints)
    val yCoords = IntArray(numKeypoints)
    val confidenceScores = FloatArray(numKeypoints)
    keypointPositions.forEachIndexed { idx, position ->
        val positionY = keypointPositions[idx].first
        val positionX = keypointPositions[idx].second
        yCoords[idx] = (
                position.first / (height - 1).toFloat() * bitmap.height +
                        offsets[0][positionY][positionX][idx]
                ).toInt()
        xCoords[idx] = (
                position.second / (width - 1).toFloat() * bitmap.width +
                        offsets[0][positionY]
                                [positionX][idx + numKeypoints]
                ).toInt()
        confidenceScores[idx] = sigmoid(heatmaps[0][positionY][positionX][idx])
    }

    val person = Person()
    val keypointList = Array(numKeypoints) { KeyPoint() }
    var totalScore = 0.0f
    enumValues<BodyPart>().forEachIndexed { idx, it ->
        keypointList[idx].bodyPart = it
        keypointList[idx].position.x = xCoords[idx]
        keypointList[idx].position.y = yCoords[idx]
        keypointList[idx].score = confidenceScores[idx]
        totalScore += confidenceScores[idx]
    }

    person.keyPoints = keypointList.toList()
    person.score = totalScore / numKeypoints

    return person
}
```

The whole .kt file is the heart of bitmap to points on screen!

If you need anything else tag me.

Happy coding

Comment: Thanks for your reply and sorry about my late response, because after a while my project is still there and not finished, maybe I will comeback with it later.
Anyway the example is great and I think I will be able to make it work. I'll try to put some more effort xD